# For() não está percorrendo todas as vezes que deveria

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
geraVariacoes(){
    let produto = new Array()
    console.log(this.listaValorAtributosColunaUm.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < this.listaValorAtributosColunaUm.length; i++) { 
        produto.push({
          sku: this.listaValorAtributosColunaUm[i].sku,
          id_atributo_principal: this.listaValorAtributosColunaUm[i].idatributo,
          estoque_variacao: this.listaAtributosSequencia.estoque,
          preco_variacao: this.listaAtributosSequencia.preco_variacao,
          foto_prin_1: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_1,
          foto_prin_2: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_2,
          foto_prin_3: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_3,
          foto_prin_4: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_4,
          foto_prin_5: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_5,
          foto_prin_6: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_6
        }
    )
}
```

No meu `console.log(this.listaValorAtributosColunaUm.length)` é impresso o valor 3. porém, quando eu dou `console.log(produto)` apenas um elemento é inserido no array.

Também tentei: `let produto = []`
Porém continua não adicionando os elementos na minha variável produto, adiciona apenas o primeiro.

Nenhuma mensagem de erro é mostrada no console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código está com erro de formatação, está faltando fechar a função, veja abaixo:

```js
geraVariacoes(){
    let produto = new Array()
    console.log(this.listaValorAtributosColunaUm.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < this.listaValorAtributosColunaUm.length; i++) { 
        produto.push({
          sku: this.listaValorAtributosColunaUm[i].sku,
          id_atributo_principal: this.listaValorAtributosColunaUm[i].idatributo,
          estoque_variacao: this.listaAtributosSequencia.estoque,
          preco_variacao: this.listaAtributosSequencia.preco_variacao,
          foto_prin_1: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_1,
          foto_prin_2: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_2,
          foto_prin_3: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_3,
          foto_prin_4: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_4,
          foto_prin_5: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_5,
          foto_prin_6: this.listaAtributosSequencia.foto_prin_6
        })
    }
}
```